Updating multiple non-consecutive columns in mysql
I am learning mysql basics syntaxes on MySQL Command Line and I ran to a problem below.
I have a former database but later have new columns updated.
This is the former database:
id name owner birth
1 Sandy Rasey 2015-01-03
2 Cookie Casey 2013-11-13
3 Charlie River 2016-05-21

Later it got updated with more columns, and I want to update it's variables:
+----+---------+-------+------------+--------+------------+------+------+---------+
| id | name    | breed | coloration | owner  | birth      | age  | sex  | fav_toy |
+----+---------+-------+------------+--------+------------+------+------+---------+
|  1 | Sandy   | NULL  | NULL       | Lennon | 2015-01-03 | NULL | NULL | NULL    |
|  2 | Cookie  | NULL  | NULL       | Casey  | 2013-11-13 | NULL | NULL | NULL    |
|  3 | Charlie | NULL  | NULL       | River  | 2016-05-21 | NULL | NULL | NULL    |
+----+---------+-------+------------+--------+------------+------+------+---------+

I could solve it manually using
update cats set breed = 'England', coloration = 'black', age = '18',sex='male',fav_toy='diy' 
where name = 'Sandy';
+----+---------+---------+------------+--------+------------+------+------+---------+
| id | name    | breed   | coloration | owner  | birth      | age  | sex  | fav_toy |
+----+---------+---------+------------+--------+------------+------+------+---------+
|  1 | Sandy   | England | black      | Lennon | 2015-01-03 |   18 | male | diy     |
|  2 | Cookie  | NULL    | NULL       | Casey  | 2013-11-13 | NULL | NULL | NULL    |
|  3 | Charlie | NULL    | NULL       | River  | 2016-05-21 | NULL | NULL | NULL    |
+----+---------+---------+------------+--------+------------+------+------+---------+

but I wonder if there is a more optimal way to do it efficiently.
I also tried using another code on the internet like below
mysql> insert into cats(breed,coloration,age,sex,fav_toy) values
    -> ('England','black','18','male','diy'),
    -> ('Poland','orange','14','female','yoyo'),
    -> ('Finland','gray','10','female','books');

But it seems that it can't be updated due to columns not being consecutive.

Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to just reinsert all the data, including the new columns.

Or read up https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

The consecutivity effects nothing because you specify definite columns names in definite order.

The most problem is a source of additional data which should be used for new columns updating. You show the query (which is INSERT and not UPDATE) with additional data... but I do NOT see the criteria which allows to understand which additional data to which base row should be attached.

Unless you use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, INSERT will just add new rows (or fail if there's unique key conflicts), it doesn't modify existing rows.

BTW you only need this in 2033, since born in 2015 and age=18, so you have time to figure it out...

Oh I also forgot that I also used  inesrt into cats(columns) values ... where name ='Cookie'. But it seems not to be the right syntax that could run :")
